# How to retrieve the score value for every user in firebase to display in a leaderboard

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database which stores each users score, tied to their UID. I want to add a leaderboard to my android studio app. I am not sure how to retrieve the score for each user within the database, for a leaderboard.

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

Im not sure how to retrieve the points for each user

I have used this code to retrieve the current logged in user's username from the users table:

```js
    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    Button training, leaderboard;
    Button signOut;
    TextView welcome;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        databaseUsers = database.getReference("Users");
        leaderboard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leaderboard);
        training = (Button) findViewById(R.id.training_button);
        signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_message);

        String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference username = databaseUsers.child(id).child("username");

        username.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData mutableData) {
                String name = mutableData.getValue(String.class);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, @Nullable DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String username = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                System.out.println("The username is: " + username);
                welcome.setText("Welcome back " + username +"!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Im not sure if it should be something along these lines to retrieve all scores within the database? I can only get information for the currently logged in user

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you have tried so far that isn't working the way you expect.  The documentation for querying Realtime Database on Android can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Please don't repost the same problem multiple times. If you made progress on this, edit your question to include that, as Doug asked.